# Is it expensive to open a http connection in intranet?

Tags: java, sockets, http

One server will use http client to upload some data from another server, which has a http server running.

We have two options:

1. Open a persistent connection, hold it, and try to upload different files if need
2. Open a non-persistent connection, upload a file one time. Get new connection next time.

If the servers are all in the same intranet, and the network is good. Is it expensive to create a new connection each time, if choose option 2?

---

I forgot to say: We are using `https` connections

Comment: HTTP 1.1 persistent connections have by definition less overhead than non-persistent ones. I think however that in a local network, this overhead will be pretty negligible. If you really want to use the fastest protocol possible, why not try SPDY ?

Comment: If you're using SSL/TLS, then I would consider connection establishment to be relatively expensive. Otherwise you can safely ignore this performance risk, assuming a good network.

Answer (score 1):

Its a trade-off here, if you think bandwidth will be the major issue for your transfer then going with option 2 is the right thing to do. Although this will be a little expensive on the server processing side, because there will be multiple sessions for each user and also it will  increase arithmetically with the number of users. The server jobs will be short and would end quickly so very less time for starving. number of users that can be processed simultaneously will also increase, since the connections are short. There is one con though, if there is a sequence to these files, you will have to maintain that at server end.
On the other hand  if you go with option 1. The management on server side becomes a lot easier on the processing front. Also it will consume more bandwidth. Since there is a persistent connection the number of users that can process the uploading will be far less.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend the frequency of the connection being made. Having a less congested network will allow fluent performance in both the cases though using SSL/TLS would add some overhead considering low number of clients in the intra-net space. But in case you are making transactions in frequent manner, than in such case, I would prefer persistent connection reducing new connection overhead.

On the other side, if we are taking about huge number of transactions from large number of connections for a server with low capabilities, then making a persistent connection may congest the network and will certainly take a test of the server. So we'll have to make choices taking various factors into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2. Latency is one of the biggest factors to look at in making a TCP connection. Because you are in a private network, The cost of creating a new non-SSL connection is insignificant.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you want to minimize latency then you should re-use connections where possible, especially over SSL. The cost of setting up and tearing down connections is not negligible. There are many other factors that can influence latency and you should run performance tests to verify where your bottleneck is, but to make a blanket claim that the cost of creating new connections is insignificant is simply wrong. Even on a private network establishing a connection requires several round-trips to complete the handshake which can add tens of milliseconds (or more) to your call latency.

Comment: @CameronSkinner Thanks! I meant the cost is insignificant for a non-SSL connection on a local network. Updated the answer to fix this.